# Execute byte array as an exe

Tags: c#

I would like to execute a program stored in a byte array which is not necessarily a .NET executable without creating a new file. Currently I am using this code but it only works for .net exes :

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyBuffer);
var entryPoint = assembly.EntryPoint;
var commandArgs = new string[0];
var returnValue = entryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { commandArgs });
```

Comment: .net assemblies are very different from native dlls. In fact, the CIL in .net lives in the "comments" section of the dll container.

Comment: My guess would be you have to emulate the system it was written for and have that system run the executeable. Essentially this is what you have written for C#, now you have to write it for every system and find a way to differentate the executeables. Whats the usecase - maybe there are other solutions to your problem.

Comment: If I was writing a virus scanner and I required some heuristic algorithms to check for bad behaviour, I think generating an executable from a byte array in memory and launching it would rank quite highly in my list of 'looks pretty dodgy to me' things.

Answer (score 3):

`Assembly.Load` is used to load .NET assemblies.

It sounds like you just want to start a new process - so use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process) and [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo) classes after saving the file to disk first:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("tmp.exe", assemblyBuffer);
Process process = Process.Start("tmp.exe", commandArgs);
```

I think you'll find it hard to launch an executable without saving it to a file system first, although that could be an in-memory file system.

Comment: What is that `ProcessBuilder`? It seems now you changed it to `ProcessStartInfo`

Comment: No I know about those classes I want to run an executable which is stored in my program as a byte array. It's an honor to be answered by you by the way.

Comment: I need to do it without creating a new file.

Comment: @Saje: Then you're out of luck, basically. *Why* do you think you need to do it without creating a new file?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: It was a brain fart - I was getting confused with Java.